# GWT back-end intercepting/blocking external requests

Tags: java, gwt

My company’s web application is using GWT both for front-end and back-end and we’d like to remove GWT from the project. Our current objective would be to make a new login page in Angular2 using the existing GWT back-end.

The main problem we encounter at the moment is that all the requests coming from outside the current GWT front-end seem to be intercepted/blocked and don’t return anything. I’m currently using Postman to make GET requests from the server. 
Here is the URL I’m calling : http://localhost:9997/RestServer/api/users/1.

Postman’s response: 
« Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://localhost:9997/RestServer/api/users/1. »

GWT Development Mode’s console returns an error:

```
[TRACE] Connection received from 127.0.0.1:60296 
[ERROR] Unrecognized command for client; closing connection 

com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelException: Invalid message type 71
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel$Message.readMessageType(BrowserChannel.java:1135)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:222)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Have you got any idea why my requests are intercepted? Why I can't even receive a http response?

If you need more informations to answer just ask for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 9997 in the old dev mode is *not* an HTTP server. This is the port on which the legacy browser plugin (unsupported in modern FF and Chrome due to breaking changes in those browsers) would connect to run Java code and enable remote debugging, hotswapping, etc.

Instead, you need to connect to the HTTP port, which is 8888 or 8080 or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, that was a stupid mistake but I would never have thought about this.